# Safest way to pass data into a controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm integrating PayPal into my Laravel 5 site.

I have this function:

```
public function getCheckout() {
    $payer = PayPal::Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    return Input::all();
    $amount = PayPal:: Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('USD');
    $amount->setTotal(42); // This is the simple way,

    // you can alternatively describe everything in the order separately;
    // Reference the PayPal PHP REST SDK for details.

    $transaction = PayPal::Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);
    $transaction->setDescription('Bid Purchase');

    $redirectUrls = PayPal:: RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(action('PayPalController@getDone'));
    $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(action('PayPalController@getCancel'));

    $payment = PayPal::Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('sale');
    $payment->setPayer($payer);
    $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
    $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    $response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
    $redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;

    return Redirect::to($redirectUrl);
}
```

I want to be able to select the `setTotal` amount before going to `getCheckout()`.

What would be the safest way to do this so the values can't be tampered with?

Thanks

Comment: You can NEVER trust any kind of user input. I'm afraid that as long as you don't set any kind of server-side script for this you won't be able to make this process safe.

There are some solutions coming to my mind, like sending a "signature" generated using a algorithm both in front-end and backend, so you could validate this signature and see if anybody modified the request. However, this method is not really good as it bases safety in hidden details, so if somebody reverses this algorithm to calculate the signature you'll be exposed.

Can you explain the whole process a user would follow?

Comment: @Jesús Thanks for your response. Basically I need to find a way for the user to select how much they will be paying. And then depending on what they selected, `$amount-setTotal();` would be different. I'd bein control of what they can select (a dropdown box for example). Say $10, $50, $100. Does that make sense?

Comment: From my understanding, what you want to do is to set the amount that one user can pay just to a few values, so they cannot put any value outside of these accepted values. What about just checking the number that you have in that field using the Validation class (or any other method) and seeing if it's any of the accepted values?

Comment: @Jesús I want to do that too, but I'm wondering how I get the users selection from the view, into that variable?

Comment: Just make a request to a controller containing that function and retrieve the input from the request object. More info here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#retrieving-input